# Ionic2 Cordova Plugin not accessible

Tags: cordova, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I installed the x-toaster plugin in my ionic2 project with:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-toast --save
```

In Code I try:

```
window['plugins'].toast.show(message, "short", position);
```

Above does not seem to get hold of the plugin.

[image]

### My Component:

```
 constructor(
        public  navController:  NavController,
        private formBuilder:    FormBuilder,
        private goalService:    GoalService,
        private authService:    AuthService,
        private navService:     NavService,
        public platform:        Platform
    ) {
        super()
        this.contractForm = formBuilder.group({
            termsAccepted: [false, Validators.required],
        })
    }

     showToast(message, position) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            window['plugins'].toast.show(message, "short", position);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Define "nothing of the above is working". *What* isn't working? Any error message? What have you tried so far?

Comment: See updated screenshot

Comment: Do I need to import or inject that cordova plugins somehow?

Comment: see below answer, yet it does show the toaster. but.. no more console errors..

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Toast } from 'ionic-native'
```

then in code do `Toast.`

.. however it is still not showing, fortunately all console errors are gone. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1)

```
import . . .
import . . .
declare var cordova;
. 
.
.
cordova.plugins.toast.show(message, "short", position);
```

2)

```
(<any>window).plugins.toast.show(message, "short", position);
```